# Answer type mismatch query type with dns Dig tool

Tags: dns, dig

When I did dns domain query with "dig @server domain type"

```
[root@centos ~]# dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com aaaa

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-61.el7_5.1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.google.com aaaa
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10074
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     249 IN  A   69.63.184.14

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 28 18:44:16 CST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

What is the matter with that? I tried to tcpdump the network traffic, it was:

[Tcpdump the dig processing packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YttwR.jpg)

Comment: 4ms is way to fast. It is very unlikely to come from Google. Even my dedicated server takes 14ms to receive a reply from 8.8.8.8.

Comment: @DanielB: Yes, this one is definitely fake – but in general it depends on where it is physically located and how good the host's connectivity is (Google offers direct peerings). 5–6ms is perfectly normal on my cheapo VPS, with ping time being 1–2ms, simply because it is very close to AMS-IX.

Comment: `69.63.184.14` belongs to Facebook, by the way.

Comment: Yes, it is too fast than normal network ping. it is dns poisioning, nothing to do with  "dig". Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each DNS query generates exactly one reply. If you get three, that means the other two aren't coming from the real 8.8.8.8 server – they're coming from elsewhere, i.e. there is a malicious device in your path to the internet. (Do these packets show different TTLs in their IP headers?)

Contact your ISP / your network administrators.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, the TTLs in the IP headers are different, those in the A record dns answer packet is 51, the third one in AAAA record answer is 104, there must be a malicious device int the path.